# overlay colored boxplots on parallel coordinate plots with faceting in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following example.

```
require(ggplot2)
# Example Data
x <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(800,0,1),
                var2=rnorm(800,0,1),
                var3=rnorm(800,0,1),
                type=factor(rep(c("x", "y"), length.out=800)),
                set=factor(rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each=200))
                )
```

Now, I would like to plot (thin) parallel coordinate plots of these lines, with points for each of the variable values. I would like to overlay a boxplot (each of a different color for each method) on these parallel coordinate plots at the variables values. On top of this, I would like to facet for the groups and types, say using set~type. Is this possible to do using ggplot2?

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put data in long format first. I didn't put in points, since the graph is already cluttered enough, but you can do so by adding a `geom_point`.

```
require(tidyr)
x$id <- 1:nrow(x)
x2 <- gather(x, var, value, var1:var3)
```

## Boxplots

```
ggplot(x2, aes(var, value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = id), size = 0.05, alpha = 0.3) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = var), alpha = 0.5) + 
  facet_grid(set ~ type) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

## Or perhaps violins

Replacing the boxplots with violins looks pretty cool as well.

```
ggplot(x2, aes(var, value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = id), size = 0.05, alpha = 0.3) + 
  geom_violin(aes(fill = var), col = NA, alpha = 0.6) +
  facet_grid(set ~ type) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do I change the line color, and also the width of the lines in the boxplot? Is it possible to make the boxes in the boxplot thinner? Violinplot looks cool.

Comment: OK, got the color for the lines: need to add I("orange") as the colour to the geom_line. Still looking for how to make the lines in the boxes in the boxplot thinner.

Comment: The boxplot lines are made thinner by the use of (R syntax) lwd.

Comment: Yeah it seems you have it figured out.
`ggplot(x2, aes(var, value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = id), size = 0.05, alpha = 0.3, col = 'orange') + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = var), alpha = 0.5, lwd = 0.1) +
  facet_grid(set ~ type) + theme_bw()`

Comment: Thanks again! Btw, what does the group=id in aes() do?

Comment: It tells ggplot2 which points should be connected in a line, one line per group.